# How the multiplication in Ring-LWE is defined?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory, cryptography

in the original paper of Ring-LWE (https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/230.pdf), page 18, definition 3.1, they take a cyclotomic ring of integers $R$, and a prime number $q$, and then multiply an element $a$ from $R_q=R/qR$ with another element $s$ in $R_q^{\vee}=R^{\vee}/qR^{\vee}$.

My question is how they can define such multiplication?

Comment: What is $R^{\vee}$?

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer You can think of $R^{\vee}$  as a fractional ideal in the number field, and it contains $R$.

Comment: If you think of $R^{\vee}/qR^{\vee}$ as the ring of residue classes modulo $q$ represented by elements in some fractional ideal, then you can certainly multiply such residue classes by an arbitrary residue class $a$ modulo $q$.